# How to access two databases?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, driver, oracle-call-interface

I have an Oracle database and another **replicated** (the both database are synchronized).

For availability reason, I want when the initial database is inactive, I go to another through my Java program.

What is the driver to use? How?

Comment: just check if the connection is null then create connection with another database. if you post your connection code then we can help better

Comment: The driver still remains oracle (since you're talking to the oracle database). In your configuration file, you'll have two connection strings. The code will fall back to one of those connections if the other one fails to respond.

Comment: I want that the driver switches automatically to another database

Comment: The driver won't switch automatically. You can do the failover yourself with just a few lines of code: configure the two connection strings, open the first one, if no connection, open the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you create services in the database and make the application connect using the service name instead of the physical connect items like ORACLE_SID or instance name.

The connect string should contain the backup connection[s]. The application will connect to the first possible database where the requested service runs. If that database fails, sql*net will failover the connection to one of the remaining databases, provided that the service also runs there, or that the service has been relocated to one of the remaining databases.

There are lot's of options for this. Start reading [Oracle Maximum Availability Architecture - MAA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/availability/maa-096107.html) Lookout for global package state variables ...